# Team Foundation Server also loses code at check-in just like the SourceSafe

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

So we have Team Foundation Server running in replacement of our old SourceSafe for about a couple of months now and I've just had the first serious fallout. Just the same what was regularly happening all the time with the SourceSafe.

I check in a file, its content arrives only partially into repository. The rest is got lost on the way.

This time I alone was working on the file. So no interim check-ins by other colleagues. Also no conflicts reported. About half of the file is missing, all that I have implemented today until the lunch time.

What's wrong with it? It's way more expensive than SourceSafe. Why doesn't it work proportionally better?

Comment: never had TFS lose a file. Had other problems, but never that....

Comment: More of a rant than a question, really.  As with Mitch, I've never had problems with TFS losing a file and I've been using it for 3 years.

Comment: So it's probably a cosmic radiation in our office then.

Comment: maybe look at your network infrastructure?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by " its content arrives only partially into repository".

Comment: I mean I check in a file and the version in repository does not correspond to what was attempted to check in. Yesterday the file contained one class, today I added three nested classes into it and checked it in. The repository version though had a class with just one nested class. I'm 100% sure I sent the right version since I compiled it, tested it and only then sent to the rep. Me and our seniour guy are both puzzled...

Comment: There is as well a correct record in the file history. It was really checked in by me at exactly that time.

Comment: Using VSS for 10 years and never lost anything.  3 years with TFS I've never lost anything.  I would say that if you are having the same issues with both systems, it smells like user error to me.  Is it possible you have multiple workspaces with the file checked out to both (like a laptop and a workstation)?

To be fair, TFS costs more because it is a lifecycle management platform (testing, builds, requirements, dev, source control).  It is free if you have 5 or less on your team.

Comment: It's a usual thing that a file be checked out by multiple users. That goes for many years. Isn't it how we are supposed to work with these systems?

Comment: @Mastermind: TFS doesn't make mistakes like this. That strongly suggests you've done something wrong yourself.

Comment: Totally agree with others that TFS does not make mistakes like this. I suggest you look at how you are using TFS. We have multiple checkout to many devs and do merges all the time with very few problems. I have found that TFS does not seem to  :)like a rename followed by a delete! :)

Comment: Answer #1: use [subversion|mercurial|git|zip files]. Answer #2: get a blog.

Comment: +1 to counter downvotes. Yes, this may be user error or misunderstanding, but as a TFS newbie myself I've ended up in similar situations, quite confused at times as to what exactly I have and haven't checked in and where parts of my files have gone. It sounds like two people had the file checked out at the same time and one of them forgot to run "Get latest version" before checking in. Or perhaps they'd run "Get latest version" when they shouldn't have.

Answer (score 3):

When you check a file in it checks the file from the disk in, not what is currently being shown in the IDE, so if you haven't saved the changes it won't check in your changes.

This is the same as with the msbuild process, which is why there is an option to save the files before building in VS.  It's because the compiler and the source control are external applications that are being called from the IDE.

Comment: +1, this has happened to me when working with multiple open IDE's. Checkin from IDE 1, didnt save files from IDE 2 first.